# Using PapaParse with npm and browserify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, papaparse

I'm trying to use [PapaParse with browserify and npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/papaparse).

I have installed the package with `npm i --save papaparse` and it is in the `node_modules` folder.

This is my `index.js` file:

```
var Papa = require('papaparse');

getData: function() {
    Papa.parse(_this.globalOptions.numeratorUrl, {
        download: true,
        header: true,
        error: function(err, file, inputElem, reason) {
            ...
        },
        complete: function(numeratorData) {
            ...
        }
   });
}),
```

But with this I get `Uncaught TypeError: Papa.parse is not a function`.

What am I doing wrong? Or at least, how can I debug this?

Comment: Can you run Papa.parse() outside of getData?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [baby parse](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/BabyParse) project which has been forked from papa parse?

I've had good results with it so far with a project I'm working on.